# How does lazy module loading work in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, ecmascript-6

In this [typescript book section](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/globals.html) the author explains lazy loading with the following example:

```
import foo = require('foo');

export function loadFoo() {
    // This is lazy loading `foo` and using the original module *only* as a type annotation
    var _foo: typeof foo = require('foo');
    // Now use `_foo` as a variable instead of `foo`.
}
```

According to the author typescript only loads the type of `foo` on the first call to `require` but on the second call when a `foo` var is created it loads the entire module required to create the `var _foo`.

How does this work.  Can someone show a more detailed example of what's going on under the hood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's mentioned in the [typescript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios)

> The compiler detects whether each module is used in the emitted
>   JavaScript. If a module identifier is only ever used as part of a type
>   annotations and never as an expression, then no require call is
>   emitted for that module.

In this example, the first `foo` (the one without an underscore) is used only once in the type annotation as an argument of `typeof`, so the first `require('foo')` is omitted from the generated javascript code. You can check generated `.js` file to see that, and there would be only one call to the `require` at runtine, the 'second' one.

When `loadFoo()` is called, `require('foo')` is executed, calling built-in node.js `require()` function which loads `foo` module at runtime in the usual way.

Answer (score 9):

Typescript 2.4 now supports [Dynamic Import Expressions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html) where you can lazily import modules.

Here is the example:

```
async function getZipFile(name: string, files: File[]): Promise<File> {
    const zipUtil = await import('./utils/create-zip-file');
    const zipContents = await zipUtil.getContentAsBlob(files);
    return new File(zipContents, name);
}
```

Behind the hood it is still using `require` as you can see in the [transpiled code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=async%20function%20getZipFile(name%3A%20string%2C%20files%3A%20File%5B%5D)%3A%20Promise%3CFile%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20zipUtil%20%3D%20await%20import('.%2Futils%2Fcreate-zip-file')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20zipContents%20%3D%20await%20zipUtil.getContentAsBlob(files)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20File(zipContents%2C%20name)%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: Dynamic Imports forces synchronous operations to be asynchronous, which means your return values will all be `Promise`s... unless you fire and forget, which still may not work for everyone.

Comment: This is cool and useful if you are bundling your code so that webpack generates many many bundles and it can work out which bundle the import is in.  But it does not handle dynamic transpilation which is what I really want to have.  I want typescript, in a local env, to not transpile typescript until something running in the app needs it.  Which would need to be a webpack -> ts-node feature where it would only transpile ts that's asked for, really hard thing to do, but would be insanely awesome for faster build times and HMR refreshes.

Comment: @RyanMann did you try https://esbuild.github.io/ ?